# What is different about HashAlgorithm is new SHA256Managed() vs. SHA256Managed.Create()

Tags: c#, hash, sha256, sha

I seem to be seeing SHA-2 being done 2 different ways.

Yes I get that 1 is "newed" (instantiated) vs. a Create Method on the other but it seems that that achieve the same identical object

```
HashAlgorithm sha2 = new SHA256Managed();

vs.            

SHA256 sha2 = SHA256Managed.Create();
```

Does "sha2" act the same? if not what is the difference and why are there 2 types written?

Comment: Well `Create`returns a `SHA256` object and not a `SHA256Managed` as it comes from the base class.

Comment: Looking at the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/sha256.cs,b87ea7e64312d482), I think they're going to be the same. If you follow the trail, it looks like `Create` should return a new `Sha256Managed` instance by default.

Comment: @DavidG `SHA256` is an abstract class, so the actual instance must be a subclass.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the that

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yeah, I was just trawling the same source code that you posted. It does seem that `Create` is doing some reflection which ultimately calls `new SHA256Managed()` anyway.

Comment: It is somewhat inevitable that cryptographic software must be cryptic.  The 2nd snippet leaves it up to the user to choose what provider he prefers.  There are 3 to choose from, SHA256Managed, SHA256Cng and SHA256CryptoSerivceProvider.  Configuration is [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/693aff9y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.Create` method might give you a platform optimized version of implementation (though the current code from Microsoft might not use that opportunity in all possible places).

For example, if this call is made on a machine with hardware encryption support, it might return a hardware-specific version.

Thus, it would be a better option to avoid using a specific implementation in your own code.